# Front-end only $_POST and $_POST requests handling in WordPress plugin

Tags: plugins, request-filter

I just created a WordPress plugin with a custom template that handles a $_GET request before the HTML code. Wordpress team is asking me to put this code inside a function.

I understand that for admin panel forms the way is to use

admin-post.php

or

add_action( 'admin_post_****', '****' );

But how do you handle a front-end form post (not that of admin panel).
In what kind of a function should I put my template's $_GET or $_POST handling code. Because wordpress.org is not accepting my plugin without these request handles to be inside a function.

Comment: `admin-post` is acceptable for front-end form processing, there are actions for both logged-in and not-logged-in users. It might help to explain what your form does exactly- are you adding data to the database, filtering a query, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like this:

```
add_action( 'admin_post_add_foobar', 'prefix_admin_add_foobar' );
//this next action version allows users not logged in to submit requests

//if you want to have both logged in and not logged in users submitting, you have to add both actions!

add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_add_foobar', 'prefix_admin_add_foobar' );


function prefix_admin_add_foobar() {
    status_header(200);
    die("Server received '{$_REQUEST['data']}' from your browser.");
    //request handlers should die() when they complete their task
}
```

[for more information you can check this page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action))